# Spark Standalone --total-executor-cores

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

Im using Spark 2.1.1 Standalone cluster,

Although I have 29 free cores in my cluster (`Cores in use: 80 Total, 51 Used`), when submitting new spark job with `--total-executor-cores 16` this config is *not* taking affect and the job submitted only with 6 cores..

What am I missing?
(deleting checkpoints doesn't help)

Here is my spark-submit command:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.4" 
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.4" \
/opt/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--master spark://XXXX.XXXX:7077  \
--conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2001" \
--conf "spark.port.maxRetries=200" \
--conf "spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0" \
--executor-memory 24G \
--total-executor-cores 16 \
--driver-memory 8G \
/home/XXXX/XXXX.py \
--spark_master "spark://XXXX.XXXX:7077" \
--topic "XXXX" \
--broker_list "XXXX" \
--hdfs_prefix "hdfs://XXXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the high number of memory I asked from spark (`--executor-memory 24G`) - spark tried to find worker nodes with 24G free memory and found only 2 nodes, each node had 3 free cores (that's why I saw only 6 cores).

When decreasing the number of memory to 8G, spark found the number of cores specified.